Lower bound on variance of RV $X$ implies upper bound on $\text{Pr}[X \in (a,b)]$.
If I have a random variable $X$ (say supported in the interval $[0,1]$) and I know that it's variance is at least s, is there an upper bound on $\text{Pr}(X \in (a,b))$ as I make $(a,b)$ smaller and smaller?
My intuition is that if too much of $X$'s probability is concentrated in a tiny interval $(a,b)$ then its variance would be small, so if $(a,b)$ can be chosen tiny enough so that any $X$ with variance at least s is unlikely to fall in $(a,b)$.
This question is similar but covers the case where the support isn't finite, where it is intuitive that such a bound doesn't exist.
